# ScrolledWindow scroll by drag (simulate finger on touchscreen)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, gtk3

I am building an application with python and GTK+3, and having data displayed in tabular using TreeView inside ScrolledWindow.

Can the scrolled window configured to perform scroll, by dragging the treeview row ? Something like we do on (mobile) touchscreen.

On documentation, ScrolledWindows has kinetic-scrolling property but:

1. I don't know how to use it
2. I don't have touchscreen, just want to use mouse to simulate it.

I don't need the solution to be cross-platform, require only for Ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I hope you realize Pygtk is getting obsolete. [This](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) is a tutorial on how to use Gtk3 and Python.

Comment: Thank you. But actually, that is what I use. The window creation is exactly like that, the import is from gi.repository. So i guess, i am already using gkt3.

Comment: The latest Gtk+-3.0 already has builtin kinetic scrolling on most *view widgets. (Not sure from which version, Fedora 23 already had it)

Comment: @JoséFonte I did read about kinetic scrolling property. But it doesn't work. May be because I dont have touchscreen. How to enable the feature using mouse (drag) ?

Comment: @Lee i think you must emulate the touch with the mouse at OS Level, maybe some tool will give you that. But indeed, mouse won't behave like a touchscreen.

Comment: Actually i am porting Java (swing) app to python, the java version of drag-to-scroll is using https://gist.github.com/martenjacobs/75d6aeb04d577de9fdc1, but no idea how to translate it into python with gtk.

Comment: @Lee I know kinetic scrolling does work with a mouse... sometimes. The sad part is that I can never figure out how to activate it again after it happens:( Maybe an occasional glitch with my mouse?

Comment: Well, to be clear, the main course that I need is the ability drag-to-scroll, so i drag the item on treeview, and the treeview or scrolledwindow, either one, scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to hook up to the `button press event` and `button release event`. This will pass in the widget (treeview) and a event. The event has a .x and .y attribute which could be used to detect how far the mouse moves.

The docs for the event attributes is down:(

**Update:**

I figured out how to do exactly what you asked. Observe the `button press event`, the `button release event` and `motion notify event` have to be on the treeview. This is using Gtk Builder.

The code of the glade.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0"/>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="liststore1">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name gchararray1 -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
    </columns>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">window</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">400</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="events"/>
        <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="events"/>
            <property name="model">liststore1</property>
            <signal name="button-press-event" handler="button_press_event" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="button-release-event" handler="button_release_event" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="motion-notify-event" handler="motion_notify_event" swapped="no"/>
            <child internal-child="selection">
              <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection1"/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn1">
                <property name="title" translatable="yes">column</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext1"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

The code of the .py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk
import os, sys

UI_FILE = "glade.ui"

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(UI_FILE)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        liststore = self.builder.get_object('liststore1')
        for i in range (100):
            liststore.append([str(i)])

        self.v_scroll = self.builder.get_object('scrolledwindow1').get_vadjustment ()
        self.mouse_down = False
        self.previous_y = 0
        self.previous_position = 0
        window = self.builder.get_object('window')
        window.show_all()

    def button_press_event (self, treeview, event):
        if event.button == 1:
            self.mouse_down = True
            self.previous_y = event.y
            self.previous_position = self.v_scroll.get_value()

    def button_release_event (self, treeview, event):
        self.mouse_down = False

    def motion_notify_event (self, scrolled_window, event):
        if self.mouse_down == False:
            return
        current_y = event.y
        y_movement = (self.previous_y - current_y)
        scroll_position = (self.previous_position + y_movement)
        self.v_scroll.set_value(scroll_position)

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The variable names should explain fairly well what they do. Correct me if I understand something wrong.

Comment: Where should i connect the event into? The treeview, the scrolled window, or something else?

Comment: The treeview. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: While i'm not really sure how to do it, i'll try. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help @theGtknerd. It works! I'll post some new question about gtk, if you see it, hope you won't mind to help. Thanks.

Comment: @Lee Actually, I check SO for Gtk questions every day or so. I think Gtk is a great technology and I want Gtk to have a broad user base. If you find my help useful, pass it on to someone else :-)